# existe alguna manera de activar mas controles si un usuario ingresa una fecha?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

saben si existe alguna manera de poder activar mas controles en un popup si un usuario ingreso una fecha y mostrar un mensaje de error al momento que deja en blanco el cuadro de texto para la fecha? y de lo contrario cuando ya comienze a escribir se activen los demas controles? adjunto mi codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto. Y trata de explicar cómo serían esos otros controles. No es clara tu pregunta. Ve a [edit] y amplíala, por favor

Comment: y sobre todo... código como texto... sino es muy complicado que alguien intente dar una solución intentando transcribir tu código viendo las imagenes

Comment: ok dame un momento no escribir el codigo por diferentes razones pero ahorita lo adjunto